# how to solve Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5

Tags: android

when I synchronize my project I found many problems and Errors:

> > ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5.
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0. Show Details
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5. Show Details
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0. Show Details
>
> ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5. Show Details

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.uhf"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/xUtils-2.5.5.jar')
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
// 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation  files('libs/jxl.jar')
    implementation  files('libs/cw-deviceapi20180918.jar')
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.1'



}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Comment out your implementation files to find out which one is trying to pull these dependencies in, then exclude them from that implementation.

Comment: Can't found it...

Comment: The problem in `    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'` but It is very important In my prog